# amStock Charts Multiple Datasets: Get names of all the Dataset selected for comparing

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I want to load [`multiple datasets`](http://jsfiddle.net/vfz2c7cj/3/) using JSON in `DataSetCompared` event. To do this I need to update all the datasets selected for comparison in `DataSetCompared` event.

**I don't find any documentation anywhere to get list(array) of selected datasets for comparing in [`dataSetCompared event`](https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptstockchart/DataSetSelector#dataSetCompared) of chart.** amCharts does this internally in many examples but I was unable to figure it out that how it understands which datasets to load.

Does anyone have idea that **how to get list of selected datasets for comparing in [`dataSetCompared event`](https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptstockchart/DataSetSelector#dataSetCompared)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chart's property [`mainDataSet`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#mainDataSet) to find a reference to the main selected data set, and [`comparedDataSets`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#comparedDataSets) for a list of references to all data sets that are currently selected for comparison.

Now, if you are using it in a `dataSetCompared` event, you might need to delay all your actions related to it a bit. The `comparedDataSets` array is updated **after** the event is triggered.

I.e.:

```
chart.dataSetSelector.addListener( "dataSetCompared", function( event ) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < event.chart.comparedDataSets.length; i++ ) {
      console.log( event.chart.comparedDataSets[ i ].title );
    }
  }, 10);
} );
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94zvajow/3/).

Comment: Thanks for editing and answering @martynasma.
I tried your suggestions but it displays blank at first attempt and displays [object object] at second attempt. I don't know how to convert this object to string.
here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94zvajow/2/

Comment: When you `alert()` an object, it converts to a string. Try writing it into console: `console.log(event.chart.comparedDataSets);` You will be able to then explore the array, and objects in it. So that you can access required parameters. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much @Martynasma. You just made my day..!